# Add data to list in MainActivity from a different class in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a list that should be populated from another class. In my MainActivity is where the list is residing to show it in the UI.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
 
    private  var listView: ListView? = null
    private var list: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    private lateinit var arrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String>
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        createListView()
        HubConnector.hubConnectorInstance.activity = this
    
        btnConnect.setOnClickListener {
            if (btnConnect.text.toString().toLowerCase() == "connect") {
                if (HubConnector.hubConnectorInstance.getConnectionState() == null) {
                    HubConnector.hubConnectorInstance.startHubConnection(
                        editTextText_ipAddress.text.toString(),
                        editTextText_port.text.toString(),
                        editTextText_readerAddress.text.toString()
                    )
                    btnConnect.text = "DISCONNECT"
                    addMessageToList("Connected")
                }
    
                if (HubConnector.hubConnectorInstance.getConnectionState() == HubConnectionState.DISCONNECTED) {
                    HubConnector.hubConnectorInstance.startHubConnection(
                        editTextText_ipAddress.text.toString(),
                        editTextText_port.text.toString(),
                        editTextText_readerAddress.text.toString()
                    )
                    btnConnect.text = "DISCONNECT"
                    addMessageToList("Connected")
                }
            } else if (btnConnect.text.toString().toLowerCase() == "disconnect") {
                if (HubConnector.hubConnectorInstance.getConnectionState() == HubConnectionState.CONNECTED) {
                    HubConnector.hubConnectorInstance.stopHubConnection()
                    btnConnect.text = "CONNECT"
                    addMessageToList("Disconnected")
                } else {
                    btnConnect.text = "CONNECT"
                    addMessageToList("Disconnected")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private fun createListView() {
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView_replies)
        arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list)
    }
    
    public fun addMessageToList(message: String) {
        list.add(message)
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        listView!!.adapter = arrayAdapter
        scrollMyListViewToBottom()
    }
    
    private fun scrollMyListViewToBottom() {
        listView_replies.post(
            Runnable { // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
                listView_replies.setSelection(arrayAdapter.count - 1)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

But I have a class that gets data from a server. Each time I get a response, I would like to pass it to the MainActivity

```kotlin
class HubConnector {
    lateinit var hubConnection: HubConnection
    var connectionId: String? = null
    var readerAddress: String? = null
    var activity: MainActivity? = null

    companion object {
        private var instance: HubConnector = HubConnector()

        val hubConnectorInstance: HubConnector
        get() {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = HubConnector()
            }
            return instance
        }
    }

    private fun setUpEventListeners() {
        hubConnection.on(
            "DeviceIsConnected",
            { message: String ->
                Log.i("TAG", message)
                connectionId = message
                var messageToPass = arrayOf(readerAddress!!, connectionId!!)
                hubConnection.send("ReaderAddress", messageToPass)
                MainActivity.addMessageToList(message) // I NEED TO ADD THIS INTO THE LIST INSIDE THE MAINACTIVITY
            },
            String::class.java
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: you may use interface as callback in  setUpEventListeners method

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can define your list as Static.
Or create your own listener interface for trigger the class from another classes.

Comment: Can you show me how to use the interface please. I couldn't find a simple sample implementation that I can follow.